# speed of comparing large vs small numbers with addition or subtraction

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity

Which of the following operations is faster? ( I am looking for a computer-science/theoretical explanation)

```
boolean value = System.currentTimeMillis() - myTime > TEN_HOURS;
```

or

```
boolean value = System.currentTimeMillis()  >  myTime + TEN_HOURS;
```

Comment: They're going to be nearly, if not completely, identical. But if you were curious, why not just run a test and find out for yourself?

Comment: I want a logical explanation: a computer science explanation.

Comment: Good luck getting one.  I would expect these to be totally identical.

Comment: A logical explanation of what, exactly? *Why* they're nearly identical? Because they're essentially the same comparison.

Comment: What's the difference between a duck?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a quick test you can run on your own:

```
public class StrangeComparison {

    private static final long TEN_HOURS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10; // milliseconds -> seconds -> minutes -> hours -> ten

    private static final int NUM_COMPARISONS = 10000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long myTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - (TEN_HOURS / 2);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COMPARISONS; i++) {
            boolean theValue = System.currentTimeMillis() - myTime > TEN_HOURS;
        }
        System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms for Comparison #1");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COMPARISONS; i++) {
            boolean theValue = System.currentTimeMillis() > TEN_HOURS + myTime;
        }
        System.out.println("Took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms for Comparison #2");

    }
}
```

And the resulting output:

```
Took 401ms for Comparison #1
Took 400ms for Comparison #2
```